# Window.scroll / scrollTo method to work in position:fixed div rather then document.body

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, window, scrollto

I have a `position:fixed` div with `overflow-y:scroll` since `e.scrollIntoView` method works fine, `window.scroll` and `scrollto` methods not being applied to this fixed div but tries to scroll `document.body`

Is there any workaround with this situation ? is it possible to make `window.scroll` or `window.scrollTo` method to work in fixed div container.

Looking forward to hear thank you.

Comment: Ok it seems i have two containers with same classes, removing one fixed the scrolling problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
function scrollto(elemSelector) {
  var $wrapper = document.querySelector('.fixed-wrapper'),
      $el = document.querySelector(elemSelector);
  $wrapper.scrollTop = $el.offsetTop;
}
```

See the demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXJMrx

Is that what you want?

Comment: Hey, it seems to be working perfectly on codepen, but this approach is not working on my SPA project. Only **scrollIntoVıew** triggers scrolling. Thank you.